# Is $\sigma$-finiteness necessary for the uniqueness part of Hahn–Kolmogorov theorem?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading [Hahn–Kolmogorov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem#Introductory_statement) which states that *"if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then the extension is unique"*. However, I did not use the assumption of $\sigma$-finiteness in below theorem.

> **Theorem** Let $\mathcal X$ be an [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets#Definitions) on $X$ and $\mu:\mathcal X \to [0, \infty]$. If $\nu, \nu'$ are measures on $\sigma (\mathcal X)$ such that $\nu|_{\mathcal X}  = \nu'|_{\mathcal X} = \mu$, then $\nu=\nu'$.

Could you confirm if my proof is fine or I miss something...?

---

**Proof** Let $\mathcal A := \sigma (\mathcal X)$ and
$$
\mathcal D := \{A \in \mathcal A : \nu (A) = \nu' (A)\}.
$$

Then $\mathcal X \subset \mathcal D \subset \mathcal A$. Let's prove that $\mathcal D$ is a [monotone class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Definition_of_a_monotone_class).

- Let $(A_n) \subset \mathcal D$ such that $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$. Let $A := \bigcup A_n$. By continuity of measure from below, we have
  $$
  \nu (A) = \lim_n \nu (A_n) = \lim_n \nu' (A_n) = \nu' (A).
  $$
  As such, $A \in \mathcal D$.
- Let $(A_n) \subset \mathcal D$ such that $A_{n+1} \subset A_{n}$. Let $A := \bigcap A_n$. By continuity of measure from above, we have
  $$
  \nu (A) = \lim_n \nu (A_n) = \lim_n \nu' (A_n) = \nu' (A).
  $$
  As such, $A \in \mathcal D$.

Let $m(\mathcal X)$ be the smallest monotone class containing $\mathcal X$. By [monotone class theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537355/two-equivalent-versions-of-monotone-class-theorem), $m(\mathcal X) = \mathcal A$. On the other hand, $m(\mathcal X) \subset \mathcal D$. So $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal D$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Continuity of measure from above" only applies when the measures in question are finite.  For instance, if $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure then $\mu([n,\infty))=\infty$ for all $n$ but $\bigcap_n [n,\infty)=\emptyset$ has measure $0$.  (To prove continuity of measure from above, you consider the complements of the sets and use continuity from below, but this doesn't work if you are taking complements inside a set of infinite measure because subtraction from $\infty$ is not well-defined.)

For an explicit counterexample to the result without $\sigma$-finiteness, let $\mathcal{X}$ be the algebra on $X$ generated by intervals of the form $[a,b)$ and let $\mu$ be counting measure.  Then $\mu=c\mu$ for any $c>0$ (since $\mu$ only takes the values $0$ and $\infty$ on $\mathcal{X}$) so $\mu$ can be extended to $\sigma(\mathcal{X})$ (which includes all finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$) by any positive multiple of counting measure.

Comment: Happy new year and thank you so much for your explanation!

Comment: +1 for the (counter)example!